# Setting a custom key when adding data in firebase when using a Model Class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to push data in my firebase using a model. However, when pushing the data I get a unique id but what I want is to use a text using newBeach.setName(beach_item.getText().toString()); to save as ID.

Screenshots:

> Database: Instead of -LcLghuLREw86jyLHwMF, I want to use "sap" that I got through newBeach.setName(beach_item.getText().toString());

[image]

> Codes:
>   uploadImage

```
    private void uploadImage() {
    if(saveUri != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mDialog.setMessage("Uploading");
        mDialog.show();

        String imageName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final StorageReference imageFolder = storageReference.child("image/*"+imageName);
        imageFolder.putFile(saveUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        imageFolder.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                newBeach = new Beach(); 
                  /* tried using
   newBeach = new Beach(beach_item.getText().toString()); 
                  but it still push a unique key*/
                                newBeach.setDescription(beach_description.getText().toString());
                                newBeach.setImage(uri.toString());
                                newBeach.setImage(uri.toString());
                                newBeach.setName(beach_item.getText().toString());
                                newBeach.setImage2("http://i66.tinypic.com/4iy2ab.png");
                                newBeach.setImage3("http://i66.tinypic.com/4iy2ab.png");
                                newBeach.setImage4("http://i66.tinypic.com/4iy2ab.png");
                                newBeach.setPrice(beach_price.getText().toString());
                               /* newBeach.setAddress(beachAddress.getAddress().toString());
                                newBeach.setLatLng(String.format("%s, %s", beachAddress.getLatLng().latitude, beachAddress.getLatLng().longitude));
                       */
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        mDialog.setMessage("Uploaded " + progress + "%");
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

> Beach.class(Model)

```
public class Beach {
public String name, image, image2, image3, image4, description, price, menuID, checkIn, checkOut, address, latLng;


public Beach() {
}

public Beach(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Beach(String name, String image, String image2, String image3, String image4, String description, String price, String menuID, String checkIn, String checkOut, String address, String latLng) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
    this.image2 = "http://i66.tinypic.com/4iy2ab.png";
    this.image3 = "http://i66.tinypic.com/4iy2ab.png";
    this.image4 = "http://i66.tinypic.com/4iy2ab.png";
    this.description = description;
    this.price = price;
    this.menuID = menuID;
    this.checkIn = checkIn;
    this.checkOut = checkOut;
    this.address = address;
    this.latLng = latLng;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getImage2() {
    return image2;
}

public void setImage2(String image2) {
    this.image2 = image2;
}

public String getImage3() {
    return image3;
}

public void setImage3(String image3) {
    this.image3 = image3;
}

public String getImage4() {
    return image4;
}

public void setImage4(String image4) {
    this.image4 = image4;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(String price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String getMenuID() {
    return menuID;
}

public void setMenuID(String menuID) {
    this.menuID = menuID;
}

public String getCheckIn() {
    return checkIn;
}

public void setCheckIn(String checkIn) {
    this.checkIn = checkIn;
}

public String getCheckOut() {
    return checkOut;
}

public void setCheckOut(String checkOut) {
    this.checkOut = checkOut;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getLatLng() {
    return latLng;
}

public void setLatLng(String latLng) {
    this.latLng = latLng;
}
```

}

Comment: Were exactly are you saving this to the database? I only see the creating of a beach, not saving it to the database.

Comment: @AndréKool here imageFolder.putFile(saveUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() once done choosing image and click the upload photo, the hashmap will be uploaded to database

Comment: That is for saving an image in firebase storage. Your image in your question is from the realtime database. So were exactly are you adding that beach to the realtime database?

Comment: yeah. when saving the image is successful, hashmap will be implemented that is why it has onsuccesslistener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve that simply like that:

```
DatabaseReference mRdb=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
String key = mRdb.push().getKey();

//set here as you want
key = "sap";

mRdb.child(key).setValue(value);
```

Comment: `mRdb.push().getKey();` is completely obsolete here, you can simply use setValue without calling push() first.

Comment: Thanks for your advanced

Comment: It delete all the items and added new item image4: 
"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/bat..."
want I want is just to update the field

Comment: I don't get it when you say it si obsolote. what should I change?

Comment: I don't understand what do you want to do exactly, but when you add data to database it is will generate a unique id for your data, maybe you need to set your own id, then you should use the code at above to achieve that.

Comment: I want to get that unique id because I have to update some fields like image 2, image3, image4

Comment: I have to HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                                hashMap.put("image4", uri.toString()); but I need to get first the unique id since it is the child